# WARN -- DICOM: Decompressing pixel values has failed

Tags: ruby, jpeg, dicom, rmagick, libjpeg

This is my code in Ruby:

```
require 'RMagick'
require 'dicom'
include Magick
include DICOM

dcm = DObject.read("export1.dcm")
dcm_image = dcm.image;

dcm_image.normalize.write("export1.jpg")
exit
```

When I run this,

dcm_image = dcm.image gives me an warning/error:

```
WARN -- DICOM: Decompressing pixel values has failed (unsupported transfer syntax: '1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70' - JPEG Lossless, Non-Hierarchical, First-Order Prediction (Process 14 [Selection Value 1]): Default Transfer Syntax for Lossless JPEG Image Compression)
```

I find that it is reading the DICOM just fine. I can extract patient information. But I can't figure out how to pull the DICOM image out and make it a jpg.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is your image valid? Did you try it with other tools? Does `file export1.dcm` correctly identify it as the right type?

Answer (score 1):

The image inside your DICOM file is compressed. It is a lossless JPEG (that's what `1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70` stands for). See [here](http://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/transfer-syntax/) for more information.

The header is here and can be read by the dicom gem, but the image needs to be converted first.

You can use [`dcmdjpeg`](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdjpeg.html) first on `export1.dcm` :

```
dcmdjpeg export1.dcm export1_uncompressed.dcm
```

and run your script with `export1_uncompressed.dcm`.